# how to redirect a smartphone to the mobile version of the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I was wondering which is the way to redirect a smartphone browser to a mobile version of the site through js or css. Thanks!

Comment: CSS can't redrict a site!

Comment: This is a MAJOR FAQ. I am surprised you managed to ignore all suggestions. Anyway here is a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400499/separate-different-version-of-a-website/8482724#8482724

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I chose not to duplicate this using the page you found since it is not a very complete answer